# How does one use torch.optim.lr_scheduler.OneCycleLR()?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I wanted to use `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.OneCycleLR()` while training. Can some kindly explain to me how to use it?
What i got from the documentation was that it should be called after each train_batch.

My confusions are as follows:

- Does the max_lr parameter has to be same with the optimizer lr parameter?
- Can this scheduler be used with Adam optimizer. How is the momentum calculated then?
- Let’s say i trained my model for some number of epochs at a stretch now, i wanted to train for some more epochs. Would i have to reset the the scheduler?

Can anybody provide me a sort of a toy example/training loop that implements this scheduler?

I am kind of new to deep learning & PyTorch so my question might be somewhat silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get some use out of this thread: [How to use Pytorch OneCycleLR in a training loop (and optimizer/scheduler interactions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996859/how-to-use-pytorch-onecyclelr-in-a-training-loop-and-optimizer-scheduler-intera)

But to address your points:

1. Does the max_lr parameter has to be same with the optimizer lr parameter? **No, this is the max or highest value -- a hyperparameter that you will experiment with. Notice in the paper the use of max_lr: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07120.pdf**
2. Can this scheduler be used with Adam optimizer. How is the momentum calculated then? **Yes.**
3. Let’s say i trained my model for some number of epochs at a stretch now, i wanted to train for some more epochs. Would i have to reset the the scheduler?  **Depends, are you loading the model from a saved checkpoint or not? Check PyTorch's tutorials: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-neural-networks-tutorial-py**

Comment: Not sure why this answer has been marked as the correct one since it doesn't seem to explain how the sheduler is used with Adam vis-a-vis momentum.